# Color wriiten to image is not the same as when it is read again

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am writing a program to apply a color filter to an image. The color filter is described as follows : 
[image]

My code to achieve such a task is :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package image.processor;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author USER PC
 */
public class GrayscaleConverter {

    BufferedImage image;
    int height;
    int width;
    File input;
    File output;

    public GrayscaleConverter(File in,File out)
    {
        input=in;
        output=out;
    }

    public boolean convertToGrayscale()
    {       
        try
        {
            image=ImageIO.read(input);
            height=image.getHeight();
            width=image.getWidth();
            int pos_row=0;
            int pos_col=0;
            for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
                {
                    Color col=new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    //System.out.println(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    Color grayscale_color=new Color(1,1,1);
                    int red=col.getRed();
                    int blue=col.getBlue();
                    int green=col.getGreen();
                    switch(pos_col)
                    {
                        case 0 :  grayscale_color=new Color(red,0,0);
                            break;
                        case 1 :  grayscale_color=new Color(0,green,0);
                            break;
                        case 2 :  grayscale_color=new Color(0,0,blue);
                            break;
                        default : System.out.println("Error occoured");
                    }                   
                    //grayscale_color=new Color(red,0,0);
                    //System.out.println(grayscale_color.getRed()+" "+grayscale_color.getGreen()+ " " +grayscale_color.getBlue() );
                    image.setRGB(j, i,grayscale_color.getRGB());
                    pos_col=(pos_col+1)%3;
                }
                pos_row=(pos_row+1)%3;
                pos_col=pos_row;
            }
            ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",output);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString()+"error");
        }
        return false;
    }

    void printWrittenColor()
    {
        try{
            image=ImageIO.read(output);
            height=image.getHeight();
            width=image.getWidth();
            for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
                {
                    Color col=new Color(image.getRGB(j,i));
                    //System.out.println("Red = "+col.getRed()+" Blue = "+col.getBlue()+ "Green = "+col.getGreen());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
```

However even if the image looks pretty much as I want it to the colors being read back by my `printWrittenColor()` method gives arbitrary color values. It would thus be my guess that there is something wrong in my reading method.

Also my expected output is :

> 23,0,0
>   0,2,0
>   0,0,34
>   ......

However what I get as output is arbitrary values of red , green and blue.

Could you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You write your output using JPEG compression. This kind of lossy compression will alter the colors slightly. Try using a different file format that uses a lossless compression, like PNG, BMP or TIFF.

Comment: @haraldK Thank you sir it worked. However the image size I get after converting this to png is almost 8 to 9 times the original. Is there a way I could save this image without such huge increase in file size ?

Comment: No, you have to decide. Exact colors and large file size, or smaller file size and approximate colors. You can't have both...